# What are the chances for every Potentiflator outcome?

Tags: coromon

The wikis [list](https://coromon.wiki.gg/wiki/Potentiflator) the chances for going from any Potential to 21, but what are the chances for gaining more than 1 Potential, and can I get any number of results from Initial +1 to 21, or is the results limited to the ones I've seen and know about? +1, +2, +4, and MAX: 21?